# Copy a circular list to a fixed length list

Tags: common-lisp

I store graph coordinates in a circular list:

```
(defun make-circular-list (size &key initial-element)
  (let ((list (make-list size :initial-element initial-element)))
    (nconc list list)))

(defvar *coordinates* (make-circular-list 1024 :initial-element 0.0))
```

Now it's easy to update `*coordinates*` whenever new coordinates must be set.

However, I have a library function that takes a sequence of coordinates to draw lines on a graph.  Of course this function does not work with a circular structure, so I would like to make a copy of fixed length.  A list or an array is fine.

So far I have tried `subseq` and `make-array` with the `:initial-contents` keyword, but it fails.  `loop` or `dotimes` do work but I was hoping to avoid iterating on each elements of the list.

Is it possible to efficiently copy this circular structure or make a fixed length array in the spirit of a displaced-array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using LOOP.

```
(loop for c in *coordinates* repeat 1024 collect c)
```

Btw., sometimes it might be useful to hide the circular list behind a CLOS object.

```
(defclass circular-list ()
   ((list)
    (size)
    (first-element)
    (last-element)))
```

And so on...

That way you can provide some CLOS methods for accessing and changing it (create, add, copy, delete, , as-list, ...). You can also control printing of it using a method for `PRINT-OBJECT`.

Comment: Thanks Rainer, I appreciate the CLOS tip.